# How can I get Ubuntu's wallpaper without installing Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-background, community

If I would like to get wallpapers from some version of Ubuntu, but don't want to install that version of Ubuntu. Are they on the web or can I unpack an iso image and find it there?

Comment: What do you mean by "not install it"? You can download a deb package from the repos. Which version do you want?

Comment: @Pilot6 I mean pictures, not package.

Comment: Pictures are in the package

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks! I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wallpapers are in [ubuntu-wallpapers](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-wallpapers&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) package. If it's not already installed by default you can install the package via the command `sudo apt install ubuntu-wallpapers`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what version of Ubuntu do you want for the wallpaper?

I'll give you some major versions. Click the thumbnail to go to the full size image.

- 17.04
  [image]
- 16.10
  [image]

Comment: Sorry, nope. The right answer was - download ubuntu-wallpapers package, it contains wallpapers.

Comment: I thought you wanted to know the exact image of the wallpapers.